# How to compare multiple files (by content, not date and hour) if they are exactly the same

Tags: file, compare, backup, corrupt

I need to compare 2 folders with files if they are exactly the same, and the files in one folder are not corrupt. I tried with Total commander but it works only with one file. I tried with Beyond compare and it didn't gave me any resoults :/ Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try this command in CMD

```
FC /B pathname1 pathname2
```

for more parameters check this http://ss64.com/nt/fc.html

Comment: Isn't there any program with gui that could do that, im not very skillfull with cmd

Comment: in CMD it wont be tough still you can try "UltraCompare"

Comment: pathname1 and 2 should be full pathnames C:\etc?

Comment: and this compares only 2 files, not whole folders?

Comment: use like this: FC /B c:\amp\\* c:\amp1\\*

Answer (score 0):

You can get the MD5 checksums of all the files in both directories and compare them using a graphical text editor. The checksum looks purely at the contents of the files, not their timestamps.

Downoad FCIV from Microsoft for free ([here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/841290)).

Then run the following in CMD

```
FCIV -wp folder1 > f1.txt
FCIV -wp folder2 > f2.txt
notepad f1.txt
notepad f2.txt
```

[image]